# Ctrl+alt+F1 won't login

Tags: 12.10, graphics, login, recovery-mode

I'm having a "running in low-graphics mode" that won't ever take me to a login screen. When I enter the kill command, enter my login and password, it flashes a date and time stamp for an instant, then returns me to the "enter login" text line. I can't boot into recovery mode by booting with Shift, or even through the bios. Is there any way I can fix this without a boot disk?

Comment: Bump it. Please some advice!